# Getting "System.String[]" instead of actual value after splitting.

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

So I have a very simple bit of code

```
public static string[] config = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + "\\documents\\config.json");

public static void Start()
{
    Console.WriteLine(config[4]);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This properly displays the 5th item in the array, which is "0x00=jU0UrZBkqPXfp8MsMoILSRylevQGaUmJRnpFbfUvcGs=7lvpCgtyWl0 : crypt_wallet". I only want the first part of the string, so "0x00=jU0UrZBkqPXfp8MsMoILSRylevQGaUmJRnpFbfUvcGs=7lvpCgtyWl0".
When I use `Console.WriteLine(config[4].split(null);` or anything else in the split arguments, I just get back `System.String[]`.

How would I fix that so it properly displays the answer?

Comment: `config.json` -> google `how to read json in c#`

Comment: I read about that, I don't want to include the library. It is unnecessary weight in the program. @RandRandom

Comment: You want to know what else is unnecessary? Writing code to do a job that has already been done for you (more than likely in a less consistent way as well).

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, @Rahul gave me an answer that inlcuded adding `[0]` to my code, that is a much more lightweight solution than parsing a JSON file "properly".

Comment: I was going to argue pros for a library, but realized I don't care all that much. You do you.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I will listen for the pros of a library, if you'd want to say them. If not, I will move on with my life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should rather be like below since you will have to choose the element to print since `Split()` returns a `string[]`

```
Console.WriteLine(config[4].Split(':')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by the "the first part of the string". But you can achieve this by using .Substring().

If you know that the beginning will always be a fixed length, you can do:

```
config[4].Substring(0, 4);
```

If you know the value will be followed by a certain character (like the "=" for an example:

```
config[4].Substring(0, config[4].IndexOf("="));
```

Comment: The length of the string would be unknown, so I had it split at null (which was a known "break" in the string, so it could be a little more dynamic. The solution I have came to is using `config[4].Split(':')[0]` instead of `config[4].Split(':')`.

Comment: @Lv_InSaNe_vL You realise that if your "first part" contains a `:` your code will break?

Comment: @RandRandom Yes, that's why I have the string splitting at the white space between the end of the string and the `:`.